# MySQL inner join 2 tables to match user number to user name

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I'm sorry this has probably been answered hundreds of time but I'm totally lost between different scenarios here.

What I want is pretty simple.  I have 2 tables "bets" and "users".

In the table "bets", I put the UserID instead of the UserName.  In the table "users", the UserName is linked to the UserID.

I would like to be able to read the data from the table "bets" and display the UserName instead of the UserID, so I will need some sort of code to match the UserID contained in the table "bets" and return the UserName instead.

The MySQL query I have for now:

```
$sql5="SELECT * FROM Bets, Users WHERE GameID = '$NGnumber' ORDER BY DrawOrder";
$result5 = mysql_query($sql5) or die(mysql_error());
while($rows5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result5)){
...
```

I can easily echo `$rows5['UserID']` but I would like the UserName (in the Users table) instead.  How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: you're joining two tables but haven't specified HOW to join those tables, e.g. `where bets.something = users.whatever`.

Comment: That's why I'm asking ;)  Never used inner joins before, I knew about it but not how to use it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [inner join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

```
SELECT * FROM Bets INNER JOIN Users ON Bets.userID = Users.userID WHERE GameID = '$NGnumber' ORDER BY DrawOrder
```

Comment: Cool!  So would I use something like this to display the UserName?  `echo $rows5['UserName']` ?

Comment: Just tried it, it does work with `echo $rows5['Username']`.  Thanks! :)

Comment: @Moob https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669484/how-to-get-value-using-join-table-with-different-values

Answer (score 0):

Replace the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Bets b INNER JOIN Users u
ON b.GameID = u.GameID
WHERE GameID ='$NGnumber' ORDER BY DrawOrder"
```