# How to get value using join table with different values?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, left-join

I have a product, user and product_click model.
In product_click, I have column `count` where I'm keeping a record, which user click which product how many times.

I have also tried

```
Product.sort_by{ |r|  r.product_clicks.where(user_id: user.id).first.try(:count).to_i
```

which giving desire result but creating lots of query on running.

product_click.rb

```
belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
```

product.rb

```
has_many :product_clicks, dependent: :destroy
```

user.rb

```
has_many :product_clicks, dependent: :destroy
```

Schema

```
create_table "product_clicks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "product_id"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "count", default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

In controller

```
Product.left_outer_joins(:product_clicks).order("count DESC NULLS LAST")
```

Now i am looking something like this to work.

But here i can't able to check whether the count was of which particular user.
If i'm adding

```
Product.left_outer_joins(:product_clicks).where(resource_clicks: { user_id: user.id }).order("count DESC NULLS LAST")
```

Then it showing a product which user clicked but not the 'nil' ones(which i never clicked).

I also tried this

```
Product.left_outer_joins(:product_clicks).where(product_clicks: { user_id: [user.id, nil] }).order("count DESC NULLS LAST")
```

but giving me all i clicked and all which no one else clicked. If someone click which i didn't then it not displaying to me.

Comment: What is your expected output? I mean, it's unclear what you wanna to show. Can you add the columns of `product_clicks`? If it's a join table, consider to add `has_many through` relation. What's `resource_clicks`?

Comment: @iGian hi, updated the question. Thanks for the feedback. I want sorted product with maximum clicked product on top by a particular user, who is accessing the app currently.

Comment: @T J any references?

Comment: @philipxy Long story short, i need product in sorted where most clicked on top. and count of click by user storing in Product_click table. i want to show sorted products for that particular user and rest products below.
Soon i will update the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While I am thinking of other ways, one straight way would be a 2 step solution.

```
product_ids = ProductClick.where(user_id: user.id).order('count desc').pluck(:product_id)

products = Product.where(id: product_ids)
```

It'll definitely improve your time and is better than your query (which is N+1).

**Using preloading**

```
Product.includes(:product_clicks).where('product_clicks.user_id' => user.id).order('product_clicks.count desc')
```

The above query should also result in the same way, however, it may internally hit 2 queries anyway.

**Using having clause - Recommended**

```
Product.includes(:product_clicks).having('product_clicks.user_id' => user.id).order('product_clicks.count desc')
```

**Update - Using OR**

```
Product.includes(:product_clicks).where('product_clicks.user_id' => user.id)
       .order('product_clicks.count desc')
       .or(
        Product.includes(:product_clicks)
               .where('product_clicks.user_id' => user.id)
               .where(product_clicks: { id: nil })
       )
```

Comment: @Farhan Thanks for taking time out, i am able you archive what you are trying to explain but here problem is, I'm not getting the product which user never clicked.

Comment: same thing happening with this,
```Product.includes(:product_clicks).where('product_clicks.user_id' => user.id).order('product_clicks.count desc')```
it not showing those product which another user clicked but i didn't.

Comment: @AnshulRiyal I have updated the answer with new query. Unfortunately I don't have a similar to schema to test it, try and let me know if there's an error or something.